# Как с помощью JPA repository выбрать данные из нескольких сушностей

Tags: java, база-данных, spring, hibernate, jpa

Вопрос не совсем корректно сформулирован, но если коротко, то суть передает.

Есть 2 таблицы tab1 и условно tab2
В этих таблицах хранятся РАЗНЫЕ данные о сущности tab.

Соотношение у них 1:1 по id.

Условно, вот схема:
tab1

```
id
val1
val2
...
```

tab2

```
id
some_field
...
```

Мне, используя JpaRepository<Tab1, Integer>, необходимо выбрать все id из tab1 где tab2.some_field будет соответствовать определенному значению.

На ум приходило воспользоваться @Query с джойном, но не получилось. Теперь, единственное что приходит на ум создать некую сущность обертку с Tab1 и Tab2 и уже на эту сущность создать репозиторий. Но не уверен что это оптимальный вариант. Может есть решения Лучше\проще\элегантнее?

Comment: Почитайте про связи OneToOne и т.д. Без связей вы не сможете заджойнить две таблицы, т.к. их ничего не связывает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у тебя в сущности нормально настроена связь, то можно использовать такой метод в репозитории. Тут например я достаю Студента по Номеру юзера, связь OneToOne.

find(Название сущности)By(Таблица связи OneToOne)_(По какому полю искать)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

@Query в двух вариантах: nativeQuery, куда пишешь plain sql, и jpql запрос. Возвращаете необходитый объект, например `List<Tab1>`, либо `List<Integer>`, если нужно вернуть только список id. При это в запросе нужен корректный селект: `tab1.*` либо `tab1.id`

Answer (score 0):

Для этого можно использовать следующий запрос:

```
@Query("SELECT t1.id " +
        "FROM Tab1 t1 " +
        "INNER JOIN Tab2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id " +
        "WHERE t2.some_field = ?1")
List<Integer> findIdsBySomeField(String someField);
```